# I am not able to click on the list item in protractor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

Html code

```
<li name="choice" ng-repeat="choice in candidateStatus" ng-if="choice!=member.candidate_status.status" ng-click="setStatus(choice, member)" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Shortlisted</li>
```

It is giving the error

```
ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible
```

I tried to scroll down the page using this code but it is not working.

```
browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,250);');
```

Please please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try scrolling the page by getting the location of the element and then wait until scroll happens before clicking on the element using promise that `executeScript()` function returns. Here's how to do it -

```
var ele = element(by.repeater('choice in candidateStatus'));
ele.getLocation()
.then(function(loc){
    browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,'+loc.y+');')
    .then(function(){
        ele.click();
    });
});
```

If there are multiple list elements with `ng-repeat` tag, then you should probably get the particular list element before clicking it.

- [Locate elements using repeater in protractor](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.repeater)

Hope this helps.